# Authentication & Authorization - Practices for today

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, authorization

I am about to implement authentication & authorization in my project, using devise, cancan, and most likely rolify. My question does not surround the implementation of these, but rather on a larger scale, how people actually accomplish a full authentication and authorization, role based access system in today's world.

My questions:

1. Do applications typically have one authentication model (User), with authorization role based access to a backend admin dashboard? i.e. If role = X, a link to the dashboard becomes available to you, all others are restricted access to this dashboard.
2. If #1 is an ideal solution, how does one do such things where the application will require a more strict password for "Personnel" (with dashboard access) vs. a general "User"? I could easily accomplish this with 2 models, but then I'm deviating from the concept above.

OR

1. Do applications generally have 2 models, say Personnel and User, where there is a completely separate authentication model for Personnel (and a corresponding set of authorizations, i.e. Admin vs. SuperUser)?
2. If this above is an ideal solution, do you require your "Personnel" to have two separate logins for interacting with the user-side of the application vs. the admin panel (dashboard)?

Do admin panels for web applications even live on the web? Or do they sit on an intranet somewhere, with VPN access and all that?

I am trying to get a sense of how this all works in today's world. Maybe I am over thinking this.

Really appreciate the conceptual help here. Your input into your own process will definitely help with any explanation of why you may be able to give!

**Update:**

Let me change the scope of this question a bit. I realize I can use VPN to run public facing application servers vs. non-public servers. The admin panel would obviously live within the non-public facing front.

Does anyone have any resourceful information on how I would configure the Rails application to have these tiered layers?  How about how to setup a passenger config file to have the admin section run on the non-public server?

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to answer the larger questions you ask (but am interested in the answers) however perhaps you would better of with CanCanCan as CanCan not longer mainteined - Pierre